# Error in Web.xml of Eclipse Java Dynamic Web Project [when a new project was created]

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlet-4

ERROR MESSAGE :

```
schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.xsd/cache/www.w3.org/2001/
 xml.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the 
 document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

When I am trying to create a new Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse v.2021-09 as soon as the project is created it is showing an error in the web.xml file which I have mentioned above. It is a completely blank project so I have not idea Why this error is shown?
Please help I am stuck at this from past 3 days.

This is the image of my project in Eclipse and the error.
[image: this is the image of my project in Eclipse and the error.]

Answer (score 0):

Well I struggled for a while then decided to do a fresh install of Eclipse by deleting **all the previous files** from the **previous versions of Eclipse** and that includes the **eclipse-workspace folder** *(if you are worried about your projects just move them to a new folder temporarily and then you can move them back)* which had some config files which seemed to be the problem. After doing a fresh install the error went away and now everything is fine.